# PHP & IIS: LDAPS Connection for Password Change

Tags: php, iis, active-directory, ldap

My aim is to change passwords in Active Directory through a web interface using PHP & IIS.

I have been following the instructions on http://www.ashleyknowles.net/2011/07/iis-php-and-ldaps-with-active-directory/

Prior to following these instructions I could not get a bind to the AD for an LDAPS connection, however after following these instructions it seems to successfully connect, yet gives an error of "Server is unwilling to perform" when I attempt to change the "unicodePwd" value.

Please note that the code below will successfully change any **other** value of a user in the AD.

```
<?php

$ldaprdn  = 'CN=Admin User,OU=*******,OU=Staff,OU=********,DC=********,DC=*******,DC=******,DC=*****';
$ldappass = "*******";  // associated password

$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldaps://***.***.***.***:636" ) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";

        $username = '******';

        $dn = "CN=Bob Smith,OU=******,OU=******,OU=******,DC=******,DC=******,DC=******,DC=******";

        $newPassword = 'blah';

        $newEntry = array('unicodePwd' => encodePwd($newPassword));

        print_r($newEntry);

        if(ldap_mod_replace($ldapconn, $dn, $newEntry)) {
            print "<p>succeded</p>";
        } else {
            print "<p>failed</p>";
        }

        print_r(ldap_error($ldapconn));

    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
        print_r(ldap_error($ldapconn));
    }

}

// Credit: http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~smp/resources/ad-passwds/
function encodePwd($pw) {
    $newpw = '';
    $pw = "\"" . $pw . "\"";
    $len = strlen($pw);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
        $newpw .= "{$pw{$i}}\000";
    $newpw = base64_encode($newpw);
    return $newpw;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLVED!!**

It turns out that by following the [Ashley Knowles tutorial](http://www.ashleyknowles.net/2011/07/iis-php-and-ldaps-with-active-directory/), I *was* successfully establishing a SSL connection over LDAP, however the error was occurring because of the password encoding.

The credit for the successful password encoding goes to [hd42](http://forums.devshed.com/member.php?u=239564) on this [forum post](http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=2148059&postcount=152), which enabled me to modify my code accordingly.

Therefore, once you have correctly installed the certificates etc in the harddrive on the IIS server, this code will successfully modify a user password in Active Directory using PHP through an IIS web server (assuming that the $ldaprdn user has sufficient admin rights):

```
<?php

$ldaprdn  = 'CN=Admin User,OU=*******,OU=Staff,OU=********,DC=********,DC=*******,DC=******,DC=*****';
$ldappass = "*******";  // associated password

$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldaps://***.***.***.***:636" ) or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";

        $dn = "CN=Bob Smith,OU=******,OU=******,OU=******,DC=******,DC=******,DC=******,DC=******";

        $newPassword = 'blah';

        $newPassword = "\"" . $newPassword . "\""; 
        $newPass = mb_convert_encoding($newPassword, "UTF-16LE");

        $newEntry = array('unicodePwd' => $newPass);

        print_r($newEntry);

        if(ldap_mod_replace($ldapconn, $dn, $newEntry)) {
            print "<p>succeded</p>";
        } else {
            print "<p>failed</p>";
        }

        print_r(ldap_error($ldapconn));

    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
        print_r(ldap_error($ldapconn));
    }

}
```